# How can I create a C# MVC Html ActionLink that contains an icon?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I'm converting and updating a very old website to C# MVC at the moment, and, I am stuck at converting a few hyperlinks.

It used to have:

```
<a href="details.aspx" class="btn_red">Read More <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

and, I have tried a few things without luck... The closest I have come is to just drop the icon:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Read More", "Details", new { id = item.ID }, new {@class= "btn_red"})
```

How would I go about adding the icon, and, whilst it feels the right thing to do, should I even be converting all links like this, or, should I just modify them as they will work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Html.ActionLink` helper method only creates a link, which is just an `a` element.  What you're looking to do is create a nested structure, wherein an `a` element *contains* an `i` element.  The helper method doesn't have an option for that.  (It's not a particularly HTML-semantic structure, so I doubt any out-of-the-box tools are going to do that.)

You can, however, built your markup a little more manually.  Something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details")" class="btn_red">Read More <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Comment: In all honesty, I'm happy doing it this way that you suggest (and adding the ID), but, I was trying to follow all the guides I have read online that say to use the Actionlink helper. In all honesty, I do it because they say to! Are there any benefits? In my mind, it is just more processing and I do not understand why I would want to use it over easier standard links

Comment: @wil: If you can find an overload of the helper method which does what you're trying to do, then by all means use it.  Perhaps those guides you have read online demonstrate how to accomplish this?  Because I've never personally seen a way to accomplish this with just `ActionLink`.